# What math theory was used to solve this?

Tags: java, algorithm

I signed up for some online code competition where one of the questions had you calculate the location of a point within x,y bounds of a 'board' after a certain k turns.  I was able to solve the question by doing K iterations through a while loop and 4 conditional statements, and it worked to a certain extent. I would always get hit on a time limit on one of their 'hidden tests'.

Let me get to the question, I was looking through other peoples code and noticed this cool prediction algorithm which worked, and not in O(k*n) but in essentially O(2*n) (n = number of statements in loop, k = number of steps).  Can somebody explain what math theory he was using?

Solution by EDGAR_G6:

```
int[] chessBishopDream(int[] s, int[] xy, int[] dir, int k) {
int k1;
for (int i = 0; i< 2; i++) {        
    if (dir[i] > 0)
        k1 = k - 2*s[i] + xy[i];
    else 
        k1 = k - (xy[i] + 1);
    k1 = k1 % (2*s[i]);
    xy[i] = k1 % s[i];
    System.out.println(xy[i]);
    System.out.println(k1);
    if (k1 >= s[i])
        xy[i] = k1 - 2 * xy[i] - 1;
    xy[i] %= s[i];
}
return xy;
}
```

Here is the question: [question on code fights](https://codefights.com/tournaments/PD2rwvrrR5MbTXWEL/C)

Thanks!

Here's the problem straight from the link above:

In ChessLand there is a small but proud chess bishop with a recurring dream. In the dream the bishop finds itself on an n × m chessboard with mirrors along each edge, and it is not a bishop but a ray of light. This ray of light moves only along diagonals (the bishop can't imagine any other types of moves even in its dreams), it never stops, and once it reaches an edge or a corner of the chessboard it reflects from it and moves on.

Given the initial position and the direction of the ray, find its position after k steps where a step means either moving from one cell to the neighboring one or reflecting from a corner of the board.

Example

```
For boardSize = [3, 7], initPosition = [1, 2],
initDirection = [-1, 1] and k = 13, the output should be
chessBishopDream(boardSize, initPosition, initDirection, k) = [0, 1].
```

Here is the bishop's path:

```
[1, 2] -> [0, 3] -(reflection from the top edge)-> [0, 4] -> 
[1, 5] -> [2, 6] -(reflection from the bottom right corner)-> [2, 6] ->
[1, 5] -> [0, 4] -(reflection from the top edge)-> [0, 3] ->
[1, 2] -> [2, 1] -(reflection from the bottom edge)-> [2, 0] -(reflection from the left edge)->
[1, 0] -> [0, 1]
```

Comment: Describe the problem!

Comment: I edited it with the problem

Comment: The picture helps a lot to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a solution in JavaScript, and I'll try to describe my approach.

First, I "manually" walked through the sequence of positions along one dimension.

E.g., on a board with width 3 and height 1, if the bishop starts in square 0 and moves in the positive direction, its position follows this pattern:

```
0 1 2 2 1 0 0 1 2 2 1 0 0 1 ...
```

Note that the pattern repeats after 6. Also note (try it yourself), that this pattern holds even if the height is greater than one. Basically, you can consider just one dimension at a time.

So now, for the starting conditions I described, I can tell you the final position for any `k` with something like this:

```
positions = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0]
final = positions[k % 6]
```

How did we get `positions` though? We did it by manual observation, but we should be able to come up with a formula. Because the numbers go up and then back down again, I figured a good way to compute the value would be to use the distance from the center (2.5 on our scale of 0 to 5). If we take the absolute value of `2.5 - n`, we get this:

```
2.5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5
```

Subtracting from `2.5` gives us this:

```
0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0
```

which is exactly what we want.

A little bit of thought and trial should show that this same thing works in the negative direction and with any starting position. For size 3, we can use this:

```
modulus = 6
middle = 2.5
newPosition = middle - abs(middle - (position + (k * direction)) % modulus)
```

Generalizing to any size:

```
modulus = size * 2
middle = (modulus - 1) / 2
```

At this point, we can solve the problem for any `k` in constant time:

```
function chessBishopDream(boardSize, initPosition, initDirection, k) {
    // this array will hold the two coordinates of the final position
    var finalPosition = [];

    // first coordinate, second coordinate
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var position = initPosition[i];
        var direction = initDirection[i];

        // simple addition, ignoring the edges
        var newPosition = position + direction * k;

        // period of the repeating pattern (e.g. 0 1 2 2 1 0 0 1 ...)
        var modulus = boardSize[i] * 2;

        // this is our "index" into the pattern
        newPosition %= modulus;

        // ensure a positive result of the modulo
        if (newPosition < 0) {
            newPosition += modulus;
        }

        var middle = (modulus - 1) / 2;

        finalPosition[i] = middle - Math.abs(middle - newPosition);
    }

    return finalPosition;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Ill take a look at it later.

Comment: Looked at your answer.  Great response!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this solution uses observation that x and y parts of position changes independently and with the same speed.

The same speed means that after k moves each coordinate will change k times. Independently mean that change of x coordinate can be calculated without knowing y coordinate.

It is hard to follow actual calculations but it has these steps

- Moves to the edge of extended board `2*s[i]`
- `k1 %  (2*s[i])` calculates coordinate after all reflections
- normalize result back to normal board